# User can't navigate if dialogue is open

Tags: popup, javafx-8, dialog

If dialogue open and user wants to open another screen or anything they needs to close the dialogue first and then navigate, otherwise they can't.

I am having javafx dialogue working but I am unable to figured out how to restrict user not navigate anywhere else without closing current dialogue.

Code:

```
final TextField templateTexBox = new TextField();

        final Label templateNameLabel = new Label("Template Name");
        final Label templateType = new Label("Type of Template");

        final CheckBox cb = new CheckBox("Set as Default Template");

        final ComboBox comboBox = new ComboBox();
        comboBox.getItems().addAll("Private", "Public");
        comboBox.setPromptText("Select Template Type");

        if (getViewModel().selectedTemplate().get() != null) {
            templateTexBox.setText(getViewModel().selectedTemplate().get().getPreference().getName());
            cb.setSelected(getViewModel().selectedTemplate().get().getDefaultTemplate()); 
            comboBox.setValue(getViewModel().selectedTemplate().get().getTemplateType()); 
        }

        final Stage stage = new Stage();

        stage.initModality(Modality.WINDOW_MODAL); 
        final Dialog dlg = new Dialog(stage, "Save Template");
        dlg.getStyleClass().add(Dialog.STYLE_CLASS_CROSS_PLATFORM);
        dlg.setResizable(false);
        dlg.setIconifiable(false);

        templateNameLabel.setWrapText(true);
        templateType.setWrapText(true);
        templateNameLabel.setPrefWidth(130.0);
        templateType.setPrefWidth(130.0);

        templateTexBox.setPromptText("Enter Text");
        templateTexBox.focusedProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>(){
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue observable, Boolean oldValue, Boolean newValue) {

                if(!newValue){                  
                    Optional<TemplatePreferences> templateOptional = getViewModel().getAllTemplates().stream().filter(template ->template.getPreference().getName().equalsIgnoreCase(templateTexBox.getText())).findAny();
                    if(!templateOptional.isPresent()){
                        cb.setSelected(false); 
                    }
                }
            } 

        });

        HBox tmpNameBox = new HBox(templateNameLabel, templateTexBox);
        HBox tmpTypeBox = new HBox(templateType, comboBox);
        HBox tmpDefaultBox = new HBox(cb);
        tmpNameBox.setPrefHeight(40.0);
        tmpTypeBox.setPrefHeight(40.0);

        VBox wrapperBox = new VBox( tmpNameBox, tmpTypeBox, tmpDefaultBox );

        dlg.setContent(wrapperBox);
        dlg.getActions().addAll(Dialog.ACTION_OK, Dialog.ACTION_CANCEL);

        Action action = dlg.show();

        if (action == Dialog.ACTION_OK) {

            if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(templateTexBox.getText()) && comboBox.getValue() != null) {
                //saveTemplateData(templateTexBox.getText(), String.valueOf(comboBox.getValue()), cb.isSelected());
                saveFilterTemplateData(templateTexBox.getText(), String.valueOf(comboBox.getValue()), cb.isSelected()); 
            } else {

                Dialogs.create().title("Missing Required Data")
                        .message("Please populate both Template Name and Template Type")
                        .styleClass(Dialog.STYLE_CLASS_CROSS_PLATFORM).showError();
                saveTemplate();
            }

        }
```

** I am using this class

**import org.controlsfx.dialog.Dialogs;**

I have also tried with javafx dialog and craete my code like that but I am unable to achieve what I want.

Comment: What `Dialog` class are you using here? (Probably best if you post an MCVE.) In the [standard `Dialog` class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Dialog.html), [`show()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Dialog.html#show--) does not return a value.

Comment: Edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

Call

```
dlg.initModality(Modality.NONE);
```

before showing the dialog ([see docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Dialog.html#initModality-javafx.stage.Modality-))